# Error: invalid conversion from ‘void*` on different g++ versions

Tags: c++, g++

```
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node { };
int main() {
   struct node* head = NULL;
}
```

fails to compile with my g++ (4.9.2, Ubuntu 15.04):

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:32:0,
             from test.c:1:
test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c:4:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘node*’ [-fpermissive]
     struct node* head = NULL;
```

**But why?**

It compiles with gcc and compiles with g++ -fpermissive. It does compile, however, with g++ (5.2.1) on my other machine.

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)
```

It also does not compile with g++ 5.1 on this machine.

Comment: Perhaps the compilers are configured differently (i.e. 5.2.1 has `-fpermissive` on by default)?  Check that out with `/path/to/g++ -Q -v file.cpp`.

Comment: First of all, you have a C source file which means it will be compiled using the C compiler. Secondly, with the same compiler version I can't replicate your problem. Can you please show us exactly how you build the source, the complete command line you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was C_INCLUDE_PATH that was set to some directory that contained tinycc compiler headers. This was really hard to debug.